# Why do programs start working when I open Process Monitor?

Tags: windows, security, sysinternals, process-monitor, windows-embedded-2009

I have a script I wrote that creates and writes to a file every 20 or 30 seconds and it has been doing that fine for the past 15 years or so on 5 versions of Windows, but I installed the outstanding security updates on one PC running the script (on Windows Embedded POSReady 2009) and it has stopped working. It has an error message of 'DOS error: 1307'. A separate VBScript called from an EXE process running as a service also no longer does its job (which also involves creating and writing to a file). However the VBScript works when run from the command line. The first script works as soon as I start capturing events with the latest version of Process Monitor (procmon v3.50). And I mean, immediately, so, although the script only tries to create the file every 20 or 30 seconds, it will be created immediately, not waiting until it would normally be created - as if the create command has been queued up somewhere and procmon has unblocked the queue. It continues working when I stop capturing events with Process Monitor, but stops working as soon as I close Process Monitor.

**Why, or how, is Process Monitor affecting the behaviour of other processes?** And how do I fix or diagnose the underlying problem, apparently caused by the Windows security updates.

(The first script is run inside a process created by a Windows service and uses a commercial visual IDE to compile it, but is not really a programming language. There is a 3rd program that looks for both files - created by the 1st two scripts - reads them, sends on the data to a remote server, and deletes the local files, and that is working fine, except that these 2 data pieces are missing when procmon is not running.)

Similar question, but the answer was not accepted, the scenario is different, and the answer is not relevant to my question:
[Running Process Monitor causes application to work](https://superuser.com/questions/1243239/running-process-monitor-causes-application-to-work)

Comment: They are scared you're going to kill them.

Comment: Perhaps it's not whether Process Monitor is running, but wether someone is logged on or not.

Comment: Trust me, it is nothing to do with someone being logged in as it still does not work after logging in (or before).

Comment: The first script gets an error message of 'DOS error: 1307' when Process Monitor is not running.

Comment: 1307: This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object. (http://www.mpltech.com.au/Data/LComputr.htm)

Comment: Could your event log be full?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your service, set it to run whether a user is logged on or not.

cfr. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2015/02/18/help-my-scheduled-task-does-not-run/

Comment: The service is a Windows service, not a Scheduled Task: it **does** run when no-one is logged in, but this part of the service only works without errors when Process Monitor Capture Events button is pressed until Process Monitor is closed.  Thanks, but it is nothing to do with logging in.